# WordPress plugin to store code snippets

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a wordpress plugin to store snippets of Python, C/C++ code. I want to be able to retrieve the snippets in a post, with a shortcode, e.g.

Here is some code

```
<pre>
[code_id="34"]
</pre>
```

where a snippet with id = 34 represnets a database post containing somd code.

Anyone knowing about such a plugin?

tk

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-content-shortcodes/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that does not work. Any short code that is put inside the <pre> tags will not expand. And if I put <pre> tags within the post itself, using the short code does not seem to apply the syntax highlighting. I'm using crayon. Perhaps question should be how to include/import content within pre tags??

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic... but I'll shamelessly [plug myself](https://github.com/brasofilo/snippets-shortcode)